# How to retrieve images from server to user using Struts 2

Tags: image, io, struts2

I have a `Product` entity, which has a `imageUrl` String field.

Products images after obtaining from user will be saved in directory:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "shop/data/product/"
```

And when user wants to see some `Product` I need to get this image from `"user.home"+...` to JSP page.

I've tried to read the image into the byte array, convert it to Base64 encoding, and then refer in JSP like this:

```
<img alt="image from user home" src="data:image/png, base64;${requestScope.image}">
```

But this solution is not working, and as far as I understand, it has a limitation on image size.

Could you suggest me a way how to do such thing?

Comment: why you are reading it as byteSream? why not serve it as static resource. You can set `System.getProperty("user.home") + "shop/data/product/"+imageFileName` as request attribute and just add this path to `src` attribute . Or if is because the image is on the server then give a relative url to the path on  server

Comment: @Amit.rk3 yes, I've mention that images store is in server. So the first suggestion wont work. Would you provide some explanations how to do the second one ?

Comment: See [How to display image in Struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15278402/573032) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18001916/573032)

Comment: So second one also won't work I guess. You may wan't to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000523/how-to-use-the-image-file-located-in-local-drive-for-printing-it-in-jsp-page-or) which talks of creating a separate servlet for serving images dynamically

Comment: @RomanC I will also try the first solution you provide with separate action. Seems more appropriate

Comment: The action/controller replaces servlet in Struts2, and you don't have to write many servlets, but many actions and no servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ( i think you have some typo )

```
<img alt="image from user home" src="data:image/png;base64,${requestScope.image}">
```

Also use this site: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/ to make sure that your output Base64 code is correct.

Comment: @Mark, please use the mention site and test if the ${requestScope.image} output is correct base64 format. The site reverse the Base64 to an image

Comment: I found my mistake and will post it soon. Taken back my words - your solution works :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of base64 encoding/decoding which increases the content length two times and slows down page loading you can use the action that returnes image bytes from the file. It could be a database, in this way it should fetch bytes from `Blob`.

In your `<img>` tag that is using `src` attribute can contain the URL to the action that returns response with a header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` and bytes written to the body.

Here's an example of `ImageAction` that serves image from the file system.
It's called

## Struts 2 dynamic image example.

This is the code of the

**`ImageAction.java`:**

```java
@Result(type = "stream", params = {"contentType", "${contentType}"})
public class ImageAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {
 
    private byte[] imageInByte = null;
    private String imageId;
 
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    private final static String CONTENT_TYPE = "image/jpeg";

    public getInputStream() { return new ByteArrayInputStream(getCustomImageInBytes()); }

    public String getCintentType() { return CONTENT_TYPE; }
 
    private String getFilename() {
        return this.filename;
    }
      
    public String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
 
    public void setImageId(String imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
      
    public byte[] getCustomImageInBytes() {
 
        BufferedImage originalImage;
        try {
            originalImage = ImageIO.read(getImageFile(this.imageId));
            // convert BufferedImage to byte array
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpeg", baos);
            baos.flush();
            imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        return imageInByte;
    }
 
    private File getImageFile(String imageId) {
        String filePath = servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        File file = new File(filePath + "/images/" + imageId);
        return file;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.servletRequest = request;
 
    }
 
}
```

This action supposed to have configuration created by [`convention-plugin`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html). So it could be used in HTML like this

```
<img src="<s:url action='image?imageId=%{imageId}' />" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So **Alireza Fattahi** was right that I had mistakes in my code. The first one is typo in `img` tag (*see answer by Alireza Fattahi*), the second one is after reading image to bytes array

```
byte[] image = ...;
```

I used

```
Base64.getEncoder().encode(image);
```

instead of

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(image));
```

So eventually this method with returning Base64 encoded image works. If there is a better choices - please left comments and answers.