# Close Encapsulating Writers/Streams for ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I know it has been the point of many previous questions to close or not to close a `ServletOutputStream` like here: [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream) or here: [Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter) or with another focus here: [Do I need to flush the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043657/do-i-need-to-flush-the-servlet-outputstream)

The general consensus seems to be **not** to close it because you are not owning it in a more strict sense. (The `HttpServletResponse` owns it.)

But what about e.g. these constructs:

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( resp.getOutputStream(), MY.ENCODING ) );

Now I'm clearly the owner of the `PrintWriter` which has some additional buffers which at least needs to get flushed (and which are flushed e.g. by closing it).

What is the general consensus here? Do I need to close the `PrintWriter` (or any other such construct as for this matter.)?

EDIT: There are valid arguments for closing the stream, too. Notable e.g. not *wanting* something else writing on the stream. And meanwhile we have with *try-with-resource* constructs which *might* change the picture. See my other question here: [Eclipse complaining over resource leak when not closing ServletOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057589/eclipse-complaining-over-resource-leak-when-not-closing-servletoutputstream)
This *might* change nothing (and my general feeling is to not close the stream, too) but *try-with-resource* above all literally screams for code like:

```
try( Something out = new Something( resp.getOutputStream() ) ){
    out.print( "Foo" );
}
```

instead of

```
Something out;
try {
    out = new Something( resp.getOutputStream() );
    out.print( "Foo" )
} finally {
    if( out != null && out.isUnFlushedWhatever() ) out.flush();
}
```

Comment: If you agree with the general consensus, know that closing the PrintWriter will close the underlying response stream that should stay open according to the consensus, and know that what actually needs to be done is a flush, don't you have the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @jb: Yes and no. This was my thinking, too, but not closing ServletOutputStream is not such a clear case that throwing something additional arguments in couldn't change it. Particulary having constructs like `try-with-resource` now might change the balance.

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter` delegates to `StreamEncoder` which may do additional work while closing. So IMO, it needs closing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OutputStream` is something you're not creating, you just query a reference to it with `ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`. Therefore if you put something around it (e.g. `OutputStreamWriter` or `ZipOutputStream`) the wrapper stream or writer will just write to it.

It is implementation dependant whether closing a wrapper stream or writer closes the underlying stream, so you should not close that. But since in most of the cases the wrappers only use the underlying stream to write bytes, it is more than enough to flush the wrapper.

In cases where the wrapper needs some finalizing, it should be (and generally is) the wrapper's responsibility to provide this finalizing functionality in a separate method. For example `ZipOutputStream` provides a `finish()` method which finishes writing the contents of the ZIP output stream without closing the underlying stream.

**Summarizing:**

You should not close the wrapper, but check if it provides some finalizing method without closing the underlying stream, which you should obviously call.