# Eclipse complaining over resource leak when not closing ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, outputstream

Regarding this code:

```
void process( HttpServletResponse response ){

    ServletOutputStream out = respones.getOutputStream();

    out.print( "<html><head><title>Test</title></head></html>" );

}
```

Eclipse complains of a potiential resouce leak because of not closing the ServletOutputStream and I might be tempted to rewrite it as such:

```
void process( HttpServletResponse response ){

    try( ServletOutputStream out = respones.getOutputStream() ){

        out.print( "<html><head><title>Test</title></head></html>" );
    }

}
```

which makes the warning go away (and for the sake of this argument I don't have to write anything else to the response).

As of this answer: [Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter) it seems to be general consensus not closing the ServletOutputStream and there are good arguments for it.

So is Eclipse plain wrong with this and I should add an `@IgnoreWarning` or are there new arguments that now having *Try-With-Resource* I should close it indeed?

Comment: Yes, the warning is plain wrong. Can you avoid the warning by making the ServletOutputStream a parameter to a (new) method?