# Does stream.close closes any enclosing streams

Tags: java, stream

AFAIK, a call to the `close` on a stream(I/O) closes any underlying streams including itself.
**Is the reverse true** ?

For example :

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("abc.txt"); 
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
inStream.close();
```

Will this closes `bin` also ?
If not, is there any need to do so ? ie : will it cause a memory leak ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this closes `bin` also ?

The enclosed stream **can't** close the enclosing stream because it doesn't know about it.

> If not, is there any need to do so? ie : will it cause a memory leak ?

It will not cause a memory leak because the resources are allocated / held by the enclosed stream and are freed properly when it is closed, but the enclosing stream may implement buffering and other translation logic which if not flushed or closed, the data actually written to the enclosed stream might be incomplete/corrupt.

So it is always recommended to flush the enclosing stream (preferred would be to close that, but if you can't, the minimum you should do is flush it).

Flushing the enclosing stream is not always enough because for the underlying stream to contain valid data, the enclosing stream might add additional padding or formatting. An example for this is `ZipOutputStream` which in order to provide a valid zip file (zip format), it provides the `ZipOutputStream.finish()` method which besides flushing also writes additional zip-file related data (and does not close the underlying stream).

You might find this useful:

[Close Encapsulating Writers/Streams for ServletOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057422/close-encapsulating-writers-streams-for-servletoutputstream)

Answer (score 1):

> Will this closes bin also ?

No.  (The wrapped `InputStream` doesn't have a reference to the `BufferedInputStream`.  It couldn't close it, even if it "wanted" to.)

> If not, is there any need to do so ?

Not really.  (However, it is good practice to close the wrapper stream rather than the wrapped stream ... because of the "output" case; see below.)

> ie : will it cause a memory leak ?

Definitely, no.  And not a resource leak either:

- From the above, the `BufferedInputStream` is not reachable from the `InputStream`, and therefore operations on the latter cannot affect the reachability of the former.
- The `BufferedInputStream` does not "own" any external resources (e.g. file descriptors).  They are owned and managed by the `InputStream`.

---

The answer would be a bit different for a `BufferedOuputStream` wrapping an `OutputStream`.  If you closed the wrapped `OutputStream` directly, you *could* lose data in the buffer that has not been flushed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, there will be no resources to leak. Thanks.