# java/jsf strange error: WARNING: StandardWrapperValve PWC1406: Servlet.service() ... threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish-3

I have simple jsf app with servlet for dynamic images and filter setting utf8 encoding. From time to time (1/10 requests) I get very strange error:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[com.webapp.servlet.ImageServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet com.webapp.servlet.ImageServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.notifyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.remotlyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.BaseSelectionKeyHandler.notifyRemotlyClose(BaseSelectionKeyHandler.java:233)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.notifyRemotelyClosed(OutputWriter.java:353)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:148)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:376)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.action(ProcessorTask.java:1247)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.action(Response.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:380)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
*   at com.webapp.servlet.ImageServlet.doGet(ImageServlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
*   at com.webapp.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here's my servlet and filter, I marked with asterisks lines referencing to stacktrace:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/images/*")
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Inject
  private FileService fileService;

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
      byte[] img = fileService.getImage(request.getPathInfo());
      if (img != null) {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(img.length));
        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
          os.write(img);
*         os.flush();
          os.close();
      } else {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error");
      }
  }
}


@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
*   chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

I have completely no idea what's going on... I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 web profile with jdk7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flushing is already implicitly done when you close the stream. Closing is already implicitly done by the container itself. You actually do **not** need to do it yourself. However, most servlet developers do it to have early feedback for the case they overlooked that something else further in the request-response chain is writing to the output stream, e.g. a buggy filter or response wrapper or something. This would then result in an `IOException` on every call because the stream is closed.

In any case, you have 2 options to treat the `flush()` and `close()`:

1. Put them in a `try-catch` wherein you ignore the exception.
2. Remove those 2 lines. The container does that for you anyway. It will also just ignore the exception.

This exception is just a sign that the client aborted the connection. E.g. pressed [Esc] or closed the window/tab or navigated away to a different page while the image is still streaming.

#### See also:

- [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream)

Comment: Thanks, I'll see next week if it's working. "Remove those 2 lines." you mean `os.flush();os.close();`?

Comment: Yes, just remove them. It's not really interesting to know whenever a client aborted the connection. You can't do anything against it from the server side on anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.notifyRemotelyClosed()
```

Somehow this looks to me as if the connection you are flushing the stream of has intermediately been closed by the remote peer (a web browser?).

Can you try `response.flushBuffer()` instead. Does this also throw the exception?