# Does a servlets PrintWriter out stream really need to be closed?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I wrote a simple servlet as follows:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // [do stuff with the PrintWriter]
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to close the `PrintWriter` out stream? If I don't close the stream will that affect anything further?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it's not you that's opening the stream, you should not close it.

The stream is opened by the container so the responsibility for closing lies with it.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 5.5 and i didnt found the any mention of this as in their docs

Comment: therefore you don't close it ;)

Comment: I had a ton of grief in Tomcat, under heavy traffic, when my application was closing PrintWriter streams. Don't flush() either, unless you know why you're doing it. Otherwise you override the containers buffering mechanism.