# The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to zip files from server into a folder using ZipOutputStream.
After archive download it can't be opened after double click. Error "The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid" occures. But if I open it from context menu - > 7zip -> open file it works normal. What can be reason of the problem?

```
sourceFileName="./file.txt"'
                    sourceFile = new File(sourceFileName);

                    try {
                        // set the content type and the filename
                       responce.setContentType("application/zip");
                        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sourceFileName + ".zip");
                        responce.setContentLength((int) sourceFile.length());


                        // get a ZipOutputStream, so we can zip our files together
                        ZipOutputStream outZip = new ZipOutputStream((responce.getOutputStream());

                        // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
                        outZip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(sourceFile.getName()));

                        int length = 0;
                        byte[] bbuf = new byte[(int) sourceFile.length()];

                        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFile));
                        while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                            outZip.write(bbuf, 0, length);
                        }

                        outZip.closeEntry();
                        in.close();
                        outZip.flush();
                        outZip.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

7Zip can open a wide variety of zip formats, and is relatively tolerant of oddities.  Windows double-click requires a relatively specific format and is far less tolerant.

You need to look up the [zip format](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) and then look at your file (and "good" ones) with a hex editor (such as Hex Editor Neo), to see what may be wrong.

(One possibility is that you're using the wrong compression algorithm.  And there are several other variations to consider as well, particularly whether or not you generate a "directory".)

Comment: 7Zip on windows has a 'Test archive' option on the explorer menu that may help

Answer (score 4):

It could be that a `close` is missing. It could be that the path encoding in the zip cannot be handled by Windows. It might be that Windows has difficulty with the directory structure, or that a path name contains a (back)slash. So it is detective work, trying different files. If you immediately stream the zip to the HTTP response, then `finish` has to be called i.o. `close`.

---

***After the code being posted:***

The problem is the `setContentLength` giving the original file size. But when given, it should give the compressed size.

`DataInputStream` is not needed, and one should here do a `readFully`.

```
    responce.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");

     //Path sourcePath = sourceFile.toPath();
     Path sourcePath = Paths.get(sourceFileName);

     ZipOutputStream outZip = new ZipOutputStream((responce.getOutputStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF-8);

     outZip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(sourcePath.getFileName().toString()));
     Files.copy(sourcePath, outZip);
     outZip.closeEntry();
```

Either `finish` or `close`the zip at the end.

```
     outZip.finish();
     //outZip.close();

     in.close();
```

I am not sure (about the best code style) whether to [close the response output stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream) already oneself.
But when not closing `finish()` must be called, `flush()` will not suffice, as at the end data is written to the zip.

For file names with for instance Cyrillic letters, it would be best to add a Unicode charset like UTF-8. In fact let UTF-8 be the Esperanto standard world-wide.

A last note: if only one file one could use `GZipOutputstream` for `file.txt.gz` or query the browser's capabilities (request parameters) and deliver it compressed as `file.txt`.

Comment: @Ксения Шапошникова Welcome; I am curious

Comment: fileName in ContentDisposition header should just be "file.zip" without path. Content-Length should not be given, as you do not know (is compressed). You should replace outZip.close by outZip.finish; closing does the JEE server.

Comment: For one file, you could use GZipOutputStream, creating file.txt.gz.

Comment: DataInputSteam is for special cases int/long and other structured data. Maybe a BufferedInputStream would do. in != null can be removed.

Comment: I've followed all recommendations except usage of GZipOutputStream. But it doesn't works yet. If I try to paste the same code into a project which just takes file from local machine,packs it and saves on local machine too (in this case server is on the same machine as client) everything works. Maybe there are some pecularities when I work with remote server?

Comment: Recapting: 7Zip gives the entire file, but Windows cannot open it. File names are not Cyrillic (e, x). Paths in 7Zip seem okay. Try as content type application/octet-stream, add one directory xxx/file.txt, but that cannot be it. I did a outZip.setLevel(9); in my code. Send your code to me joop_eggen at ya hoo dot de. It must be something simple.

Comment: can you write you email exactly, please? what do you mean to send to you?

Comment: I am getting curious to the error; you can send the current piece of code to joop_eggen `at` yahoo `period` de.

Comment: Code has been sent. Thank you

Comment: @КсенияШапошникова a bit very late, I found the error (setContentLength) and slightly improved the code.