# try-with-resource vs java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Tags: servlets, exception, try-with-resources

My RSS servlet uses try-with-resource for the `OutputStream out` of the `HttpServletResponse` and the writer for it. In some cases `SomeException` is thrown whilst generating the RSS document, in which case I need to return an HTTP status 500 to the client:

```
try (ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
     OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8")) {
        response.setContentType("text/xml");

        // Generate RSS here

    } catch (SomeException e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

However, by the time `response.sendError()` is called, the $out$ has already been closed and I get said `IllegalStateException` saying that the response has already been committed (closing the stream seems to commit the response automatically ).

If I move the initialization of `out` and `writer` outside of the try-block and close them in a finally-block (the pre-Java7 way), the error code gets sent correctly.

I was wondering whether there's a way to keep using try-with-resource and still be able to return error codes in case of an exception.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use an _outer_ try-with-resources and an _inner_ try-catch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close resources which you didn't create yourself. The container created the underlying `OutputStream` all by itself and is therefore also all by itself responsible for properly closing it. You should visualise it that the container has already put a try-with-resources around the servlet's `doXxx()` method. See also [Should I close the servlet outputstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream/1829823#1829823)

Differently put, the whole try-with-resources on `OutputStream` inside `doXxx()` is unnecessary.

Just do:

```
try {
    // Generate RSS here

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")) {
    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    // Write RSS here.

} catch (SomeException e) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.getMessage());
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you rethrow any checked exception as `ServletException`, then the container will also all by itself take care of the proper response code and message.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (SomeException e) {
    throw new ServletException(e);
}
```