# Bluemix cloud foundry java app exception: OutputStream already closed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, ibm-cloud

My Java web app (using Spring MVC) works very well in Tomcat but not on Bluemix Cloud Foundry. After each HTTP request, the following messages exist in the log and a response is not returned after method invocation:

Exception: OutputStream already closed

Any idea?

Log files:

```
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.outbound.HttpOutputStreamImpl.validate:210'
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.outbound.HttpOutputStreamImpl.validate(HttpOutputStreamImpl.java:210)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at [internal classes]
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:101)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at [internal classes]
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at [internal classes]
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at [internal classes]
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM OUT APP [WARNING ] WARNING: Cannot set status. Response already committed.
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP [ERROR   ] Error Page Exception:
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP myapp
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP /
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP Error Page Exception
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.outbound.HttpOutputStreamImpl.validate(HttpOutputStreamImpl.java:210)
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP at [internal classes]
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream is closed
3/5/2017 7:56:00 AM ERR APP ... 3 more
```

Comment: according to the log this seems to happen when it is trying to show an error page. This means, in addition to the original problem there is also a problem in the error handling.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream - do you have servlet code which is closing the response output stream?

Comment: @Henry no error before reported exception. Tnx

Comment: @hugh no i don't manually close the output stream, i'm using spring mvc. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Tomcat to develop locally, you should use Tomcat on Bluemix a well. By default, when you push a jar/war/ear, WebSphere Liberty buildpack is used. If you want to use Tomcat, use the preinstalled `java_buildpack` buildpack like this:

```
cf push MyAppName -p target/myapp.war -b java_buildpack
```

If you're using a manifest.yml file:

```
---
applications:
 - name: MyAppName
   path: target/myapp.war
   buildpack: java_buildpack
```