# Multiple Request Closing OutputStream in Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to see if this is possible. So if I make a single request and this request takes about 1 minute to process before writing to the OutputStream from the HttpServletResponse object, then I make another request that only takes 15 seconds and writes to the OutputStream. Do each request share the same OutputStream? Currently I am getting an error and I am thinking its because the second request closes the OutputStream. This is the error "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error"

```
private static final String APPLICATION_EXCEL = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

@RequestMapping(value = "/a", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_EXCEL)
public @ResponseBody
void downloadA(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_EXCEL);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "a.xlsx");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
    //long task...
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook1.write(outputStream);
    workbook1.close();
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/b", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_EXCEL)
public @ResponseBody
void downloadB(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_EXCEL);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "b.xlsx");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    workbook1.write(outputStream);
    workbook1.close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask] and [mvce]. That's not how requests/response work in Spring. Each request/response will have its own input and output.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reponse. I uploaded some sample code and still confused why a does not write out to output stream if they each have their own response.

Comment: This is also from the same user/session

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you update the question with the error and any stack traces that occur?

Comment: With the sample above, I do not get an IO exception but file a never gets downloaded. It looks like the second requests overwrites the first.

Comment: One thing to try is removing the close() method call see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829784/should-i-close-the-servlet-outputstream) for details.

Comment: Technically, that should not matter because each request has its own io?

Comment: I posted the error, which was originally being squashed. So it looks like it maybe on the client side closing the socket?

Comment: I used the resource monitor tool from Windows and saw the second request closes the tcp connection.

Comment: Ok, that’s good information coupled with the session. It seems that there may be something going on in the client code that is not handling the session correctly or something is happening deep in the long running task that affects the session (less likely).

Comment: The other reason for not closing the stream yourself is if you have any response filters enabled. If the stream is closed and they try to write that’ll fail. You should see an exception in that case.

Comment: This is the exception I am getting "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error"

Comment: So i fixed the issue by setting the href to target="_blank", this creates a new tab for the request but I still dont understand why I cant use the same tab.

Comment: Works if I embed it into an iframe without the need of an open tab. I am curious if this is how you can do multiple downloads in the same window