# Nullpointer exception while flushing ServletOutputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, nullpointerexception

Here is the exception which I get some times while flushing `ServletOutputStream`. It does not occur on every request so I am not able to reproduce it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.flush(InternalOutputBuffer.java:119)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:805)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:333)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
    at darshan.HttpRequestHandler.returnResponse(HttpRequester.java:117)
```

**HttpRequester.java :**

```
private void returnResponse(HttpServletResponse response , String responseStr)
{
    InputStream in = null;
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        response.setContentLength(responseStr.length());
        out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
        while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
        {
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            in.close();
            out.flush();  //<-- Exception at this line
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any solution for this error???

Comment: I think that stream is flushed on close. Did you try to remove the flush(); Does the NPE comes from close() then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't need to call `flush` or `close` on the input or output streams. The servlet container will take care of flushing and closing for you.

There are sometimes corner-cases where a manual flush call is required, but this isn't one of them. Calling `close` on either of them, however, is really not a good idea, and may be triggering a bad state within tomcat that's causing your exception.

See [Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter)

Answer (score 0):

Here you probably write behind content length in last block, because it might read less than 4096bytes

```
byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
    while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
    {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
    }
```