# What causes this NPE in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.flush()?

Tags: java, tomcat

```
 private void respond(String response) {

    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
    httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    try {
        PrintWriter out = httpServletResponse.getWriter();

        out.print(response);
        out.flush();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Error while writing response",ex);
    }

}
```

This code throws null pointer at out.flush(). httpServletResponse is instance variable. I have verified that response is not null. This function is being called from inside Apache's aync http client lib's CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute.completed().

```
LOG:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:234) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:189) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.commit(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:177) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:739) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:179) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:341) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:331) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:313) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.flush(CoyoteWriter.java:98) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.thruport.aje.rotator.reward.async.RewardRequest.respond(RewardRequest.java:185) ~[output/:na]
    at com.thruport.aje.rotator.reward.async.RewardRequest.lambda$new$2(RewardRequest.java:131) ~[output/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: "This code throws null pointer at `out.flush()`." => No way! It would throw an NPE at line `out.print(response)` first.

Comment: Do you have the Stacktrace? Please, edit your question and insert it.

Comment: it is impossible for `.flush()` to throw an NPE if the line right above succeeded. Your step debugger would show this fact as well as what is actually causing the NPE.

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @DaniloGuimaraes added logs

Comment: @JarrodRoberson why do you think I wouldn't have done those obvious verifications before asking  here?

Comment: Guys, stop saying _"it's impossible to throw an NPE here and there"_. The `PrintWriter` instance cames from `httpServletResponse.getWriter();`. So, it's not necessary the default implementation of  `flush` of `PrintWriter`. [Reading the Coyote code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/coyote/http11/InternalNioOutputBuffer.java#InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer%28boolean%29), it's probably a bug on Apache Coyote (I don't know).

Comment: In order to answer the question, we need more details.  Include a description of the class of which the `respond` method is part and how the global variable `httpServletResponse` is initialized.  From the few details that you have included, it appears that the httpServletResponse variable is not null, but has not been correctly initialized.

Comment: Thank you everyone for help. It got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I shouldn't be flushing here as Servlet Container will take care of it at end of Servlet lifecycle and that Buffer wont be ready for flush at this stage. this
[Nullpointer exception while flushing ServletOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644258/nullpointer-exception-while-flushing-servletoutputstream)   and this
[Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter) answers helped.

Comment: Hi. Nice it woks for you. But I must say that this is not a resolution. we should be able to call flush().