# Response Filters using ResposeWrapper

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, filter, gzip, httpresponse

I came across a portion of code that zips the servlet output before returning it to the user, it uses a custom `ServletResponseWrapper` -it's so famous if u know what I am talking about-, my questions are :

1 - now the function of intercepting the response is totally the responsibility of the response wrapper -through overriding the output stream it returns- and the filter has no effect in such behaviour ? Am I correct ?

2- what happens if any of the servlets that the filters intercept its requests closed the output stream, will the code after chain.doFilter() be able to use this stream again ? and will the filter work ?

3 why does the wrapped response solve the problem of the "output returns directly to the container before being intercepted by the filter" ... I mean why the control over the response is then returned to the filter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently used the example code from this book for my project:
[Professional Java for Web Applications](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Java-for-Web-Applications.productCd-1118656466.html). There is a good example for a compression filter in chapter 9.

I'm not involved with the company behind the book.

These are the answers to your question:

1. Yes, you're correct. The filter wraps the original `HttpServletResponse` with a wrapper, and from this moment on the wrapper is responsible for managing the output stream (but not for closing the stream).
2. It's not a good idea at all to close the output stream in your own code, whether you use a wrapped `HttpServletResponse` or not.
3. The control over the output stream isn't returned to the filter. The execution of your web app is continued in the line after `chain.doFilter()`, and you can write some data to the wrapped response, if it's necessary. But don't close the stream, neither in your filter, nor in your servlet(s).

Comment: why not to close the stream?

Comment: because closing belongs to the responsibility of the container. Don't be afraid the container forgets to close the stream ;-)

Comment: I mean, does it really affect filter behavior y any mean? I read n stackoverflow that It won't allow filter to work , but have no idea if this is true or not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter

Comment: The answer of skaffman and its comments in the topic you've linked are perfect. I still say "don't close the output stream. Closing is the job of the container."

Comment: let me know if you have trouble with the code examples in the book that I recommended. There are some minor issues.