# Creating zip file in memory out of byte[]. Zip file is never suggest to download

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, zip

I have a problem with my created zip file. I am using Java 8. I tried to create a zip file out of a byte array, which contains two or more Excel files. . So, I thought everything is alright. I do an `ajax` call for create and download my file but i don't have the popup for download my zip and i don't have error.

***This is my javascript:***

```
function getFile() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/support-web/downloadCSV",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        data: jsonfile,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("in sucess");
            window.location.href="/support-web/downloadCSV/"+data
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log("in error")
        } 
    });
}
```

***This is my Controller:***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
public class DownloadCSVController {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String json)
            throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {
            int i = 0;
            for (String url : parts) {
                i++;
                URL uri = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
                int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    String fileName = "";
                    String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                    String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
                    int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

                    if (disposition != null) {
                        // extracts file name from header field
                        int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                        if (index > 0) {
                            fileName = disposition.substring(index + 9, disposition.length());
                        }
                    } else {
                        // extracts file name from URL
                        fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.length());
                    }

                    System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
                    System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
                    System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
                    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

                    // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
                    InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName + i + ".csv");
                    int length = 1;
                    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
                    byte[] b = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                    while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) > 0) {
                        zos.write(b, 0, length);
                    }
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    inputStream.close();

                    System.out.println("File downloaded");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        // this is the zip file as byte[]
                int size = baos.toByteArray().length;
    byte[] reportContent = baos.toByteArray();

    // Write file to response.
    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    output.write(reportContent);
    output.close();

    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
    response.setContentLength((int)size);
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"");//fileName)       

        System.out.println("FIN TELECHARGEMENT");
    }
}
```

***Problem:***

- The Browser not should open a download box
- The response isn't handled in the error or in the success (ajax)

So what do I wrong or what is the proper way to do this?

In my navigator you can see the response with my file but download box not should open
[image]

Comment: Have you ever tried to use response.setContentType("application/zip");

Comment: @FreeMan i have tried but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Set headers before writing anything to response stream.
2. Remove `output.close();` you should not do that. Stream is opened and closed by container.

Second point actually not affecting your problem, its just an advice. You can read more about it here [Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter).

Comment: I do what you tell me but nothing

Comment: it's possbie navigator blocked my download .?

Comment: Not likely. Can your provide more simplistic example? It works fine for me with dummy response content.