# Should I explicitly close ZipOutputStream over response.getOutputStream()?

Tags: java, servlets, memory-leaks, io, resource-management

I have read following topic:
[Should one call .close() on HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()/.getWriter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter)

But what if I use following construction:

```
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

Should I close it or container will do it instead of me?

Comment: The javadoc for `ZipOutputStream.close()` says "Closes the ZIP output stream as well as the stream being filtered." .

Comment: @Berger, yes, it closes. But container will close only response.getOutputStream() ans will not close ZipOutputStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking the closing the outermost stream will propagate the `close()` to inner streams, closing all required resources.

It's of course perfectly possible to create a badly behaving stream, but `ZipOutputStream` probably isn't one.

In some cases it may not be enough to call `close()` on the outermost stream, but the documentation for the class should indicate any special behaviour.

Comment: Which stream is outermost in my case?

Comment: @gstackoverflow : The stream that wraps another stream, i.e the `ZipOutputStream` is the one to close here.

Comment: @Berger, thus should I close ZipOutputStream  explicitly?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Of course. You should always close resources explicitly.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes, did you? You need to close the `ZipOutputStream`, as a side-effect the response stream will be closed as well, but it's not like you'd be adding any data after zipped bytes in there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should call `close()` method on `ZipOutputStream` explicitly, [here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java#ZipOutputStream.finish%28%29) the code for `close()` method. It does the following:

- Call `close()` of super class, which is `DeflaterOutputStream` in our case
- `close()` of `DeflaterOutputStream` calls `finish()` before calling `close()` on underlying `OutputStream`.

This `finish()` method writes the remaining compressed data so you might end up with some unwritten data if you do not call `close()` on `ZipOutputStream` explicitly. So, I would recommend calling it.