# Does java automatic close response stream?

Tags: java, stream

There are two use cases:

```
1.response.getWriter().print("");

2.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.print("");
  out.close();
```

Do I always need to close the Writer like showing in the second case? or can I do it as simple as the first one?

Comment: Is this in a Servlet context (i.e., the `response` is `HttpServletResponse`)? Because if so, [please read Should one call .close on HttpServletResponse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159168/should-one-call-close-on-httpservletresponse-getoutputstream-getwriter)

Comment: Yes, your comments helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get writer from `response` so normally you should not call `close()` while doing this. The servlet container will close for you.

If you pre-close your writer here, some feature will not work.

For example, your `Filter` may throw exceptions that `IllegalStateException: the output stream has already been closed`